# REST API product in several categories

Tags: api, rest

What is the best practice to build API for ecommerce, when a product can be in several categories?

Now I have the following:

1. `shop.com` - homepage
2. `shop.com/products` - list of products and categories

Should I go with `shop.com/products/category-name/product-id"`? Then same product will be available in different URIs?

Should I go with `shop.com/products/product-id` and send category as a `GET` parameter like `shop.com/products?cat=men`?

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second definitely. It makes more sense for searching.

You should still have `/products` and `/categories` to manage these resources, but for searching products by category or multiple categories, it is better to use querystring:

```
/products?cat=category_name
```

You will be able to search by multiple categories for example.